# Zend website - public index file to default

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

Hi i uploaded my website in below url : http://zendtest.com/

It shows file strucure in website. How to make public/index.php as default one.

File structure
public_html/

```
 application
 public
    index.php
    .htaccess
 library
```

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in Apache's httpd.conf DirectoryIndex. Like this:

```
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
```